# Order duplicated six times in CT order manager

Tags: cartthrob

I noticed that a single order shows up repeated six times in the CT order manager. Anyone know what could cause this?

The orders are all for the same user and all the order items are identical. The order manager id's are the same (181) but the entry id's, the ones in parentheses, are different. This site uses off-line processing for all purchases. All code is up-to-date

In the troubleshooting section of the CT docs there is a paragraph that states:

> If multiple orders are being logged for one order, this is generally >normal. CartThrob creates an order for each attempted order. It updates >statuses of completed orders to the status you've set in cartthrob >settings » orders. If you want to be able to distinguish between >completed and failed orders, make sure to configure statuses for orders.

If this is the reason, what is the cause? Is the user doing something  strange or is the server hiccuping? soothing else?

Comment: My first thought is that users are re-clicking the button on the checkout form. Can you test that out? If that is the case I'd write some jQuery to disable the button functionality onclick.

Comment: Well, I think if this were the case, it would create orders with unique id's no? I'll give it a try...